# La constante de kaprekar (problema abajo). c++

Tags: c++

[image: Este es el enunciado del problema.]
(eso se produce en el while, donde se hace la llamada a la funcion ordenar)  El caso de los if es para evaluar todas las posibles situaciones e ir armando el numero.

### utilizo dos variables con el mismo valor(en main) porque una va de forma ascente y la otra se ordena de forma descendente.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void ordenar (int&, int&);
int resta (int, int);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int x, y, resultado=0, contador=0;

cout<<"Ingrese un numero de 3 cifras: ";
cin>>x;
y=x;
```

### en este while hllamo a la funcion ordenar por el tema de los dos numeros (en orden ascendente y descendente).

```
while (resultado != 495){
contador ++;
ordenar(x, y);         
resultado = resta(x, y);
    
}
cout<<"La cantidad de pasos para llegar a 495 fueron: "<<contador<<endl;


return 0;
}

void ordenar (int & x, int & y){
int a, b, c; a,b,c va a ser cada cifra
int d, e, f;
a= x%10;
b= (x/10)%10;
c= (x/10)/10;
```

### y ya en esta parte utilizo todos los If para evaluar todos los casos posibles e ir armando el nuemro

```
{if (a>b && b>c){ //ABC   
x = a*100 + b*10 + c;}
else
if(a>c && c>b){ //ACB
x = a*100 + c*10 + b;}
else
if(c>b && b>a){ //CBA
x = c*100 + b*10 + a;}
else
if (c>a && a>b){ //CAB
x = c*100 + a*10 + b;}
else
if (b>a && a>c){ //BAC
x = b*100 + b*10 + c;}
else
if (b>c && c>a){ //BCA
x = a*100 + b*10 + c;}
}
d= y%10;
e=(y/10)%10;
f=(y/10)/10;

{if (d>e && e>f){ //DEF
y = f*100 + e*10 + d;}
else
if (d>f && f>e){ //DFE
y = e*100 + f*10 + d;}
else
if (e>f && f>d){ //EFD
y = d*100 + f*10 + e;}
else
if (e>d && d>f){ //EDF
y = f*100 + d*10 + e;}
else
if (f>d && d>e){ //FDE
y = e*100 + d*10 + f;}
else
if (f>e && e>d){ //FED
y = d*100 + e*10 + f;}
}
return;
}   
int resta (int x, int y){

int res;

res = x - y;

return res;
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: @Alfabravo saber cual es el error de mi codigo

Comment: En tal caso tienes que recordar que las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta.

Comment: Por el contrario, tú cuéntanos por qué dices que hay un error.